# How to know when Google Maps has updated their co-ordinates

Tags: coordinates, google-maps, geocoding

I am building a Tableau dashboard where the user can click on a geocode and it redirects
them to Google Maps and shows them the location. But there is an **issue** here because it
takes them to a different location than what we have in the data.

I went through an article from this [site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110942/how-often-does-google-change-geo-coordinates-for-given-address) where it says that Google keeps updating their
dataset which is why there could be a difference in co-ordinates of what I have vs what Google currently has.

I am trying to find a solution if there is a way we can find out when the Google is updating their co-ordinates or if there is another solution to tackle this issue.

Comment: Sounds like your geocoding - Google will do best guess, if it does not have that address in its database. see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/understand-response

Comment: Is there a way I can get the latest coordinates through an Api where I can update the db with corresponding ones.